# Which is better for design, .container or .container-fluid?

Tags: user-interface, bootstrap-4, containers

I am currently developing a website but have a lack of expertise in designing the UI and since I am using Bootstrap 4.5 to help with the CSS, I wasn't sure which class is better, .container or .container-fluid? I understand the fundamentals of these two Bootstrap classes and how to implement them correctly but once again still not sure which one would be better to use from a design standpoint.

Comment: what kind of website are you going to built?

Comment: No such thing as "best". It depends on your design needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you cannot claim to one of them as best for designing, It's a matter of choice for you to go with. If you want spacing like below in the image on the sides then use `container` class

[image]

Or if you want full page layout without spacing then go with `container-fluid` class
I hope it helps.

Comment: That's probably best, I just wanted to see what the majority of developers have used if they implement Bootstrap and one of the container classes for their website

Comment: @nenur As for me I have always used container, That what suited me